# Creating Resolvers that work with an external FHIR Server

Tags: graphql, hl7-fhir

I am exploring this library
https://github.com/Asymmetrik/graphql-fhir

It does not contain logic for how to implement resolvers for a 3rd party FHIR Server.

Has anyone attempted this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll add some pseudo code below, but that library is essentially a wrapper and has no backend, so you can definitely use it to wrap other FHIR servers. GraphQL resolvers can resolve sync or async. So if we took the patient resolver (https://github.com/Asymmetrik/graphql-fhir/blob/master/src/resources/4_0_0/profiles/patient/resolver.js), for example, and wanted to connect it to a third party server, like HAPI or some other server. You could implement it like so (pseudocode so untested):

```js
module.exports.getPatient = function getPatient(root, args, context = {}, info) {
    // args contains the arguments in GraphQL format, note that these may
    // not map directly to another FHIR server for naming restriction reasons
    // e.g. fooBar in graphql might be foo-bar in REST
    
    // Make an HTTP request, use any http library, for example, fetch
    return fetch('some/fhir/server/patient', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(args) // remember args may need to be mapped
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(results => {
        // Make sure the response matches what the resolver expects, in this
        // case, a single patient
        return results;
      });
};
```

There is an example at https://github.com/Asymmetrik/graphql-fhir/blob/master/FAQ.md#resolvers, but that is loading a local patient, you just need to make an HTTP request to some 3rd party server and return the results asynchronously.  For handling errors, make sure to check out this as well, https://github.com/Asymmetrik/graphql-fhir/blob/master/FAQ.md#resolvers.

Comment: So just to clarify. In terms of translating GraphQL filter queries to FHIR resource REST parameters the library should handle that out of the box (although mapping maybe needed in some cases) ?  Also in terms of the linking resources together Patients with Medications for example is it the case that the library supports this automatically as long as the high level FHIR resource resolvers are there?

Comment: Yes, so the source code is generated from the published structure definitions. So we don't rename any parameters unless we have to, and I think that is not a common case. Its just when you are writing queries to the 3rd Party FHIR server, you may come across that every now and then.

As for patients with medications, are you thinking like an and query or like a nested query (graphql allows nested resolvers for more filtering)? We do support the majority of the parameters that are defined in the FHIR spec since the code is just generated from the spec.